# How to merge two columns from separate text files?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

`text1`:

```
    ankr 
    ankr
    ankr
    brmu
    brmu
```

`text2`:

```
    jplg1730.17i
    jplg1750.17i
    jplg1770.17i
```

I need to create this text file:

```
merged_file:
    ankr_jplg1730.17i
    ankr_jplg1750.17i
    ankr_jplg1770.17i
    brmu_jplg1730.17i
    brmu_jplg1750.17i
```

How can I merge this text file with codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0; next} {if (a[i]) {print $0"_"a[i]; ++i} \
                               else {print $0"_"a[1]; i=2}}' text2 text1
```

- `NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0; next}` saves the records from `text2` as values to associative array `a`, with corresponding record numbers being the keys
- `{if (a[i]) {print $0"_"a[i]; ++i} else {print $0"_"a[1]; i=2}}` prints the records from `text1` in desired format, keeping the track of iteration of the array index with variable `i`

**Example:**

```
% cat text1
ankr
ankr
ankr
brmu
brmu

% cat text2
jplg1730.17i
jplg1750.17i
jplg1770.17i

% awk 'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0; next} {if (a[i]) {print $0"_"a[i]; ++i} else {print $0"_"a[1]; i=2}}' text2 text1
ankr_jplg1730.17i
ankr_jplg1750.17i
ankr_jplg1770.17i
brmu_jplg1730.17i
brmu_jplg1750.17i
```

Answer (score 1):

With python:

```
$ python3 -c 'import sys, itertools as i; [print(a.strip(), b.strip(), sep="_") for a,b in zip(open(sys.argv[1]), i.cycle(open(sys.argv[2])))]' text1 text2
ankr_jplg1730.17i
ankr_jplg1750.17i
ankr_jplg1770.17i
brmu_jplg1730.17i
brmu_jplg1750.17i
```

More legibly:

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from itertools import cycle
with open(sys.argv[1]) as file1, open(sys.argv[2]) as file2:
    for l1, l2 in zip(file1, cycle(file2)):
        print(l1.strip(), l2.strip(), sep="_")
```

`cycle(file2)` cycles the contents of `file2`, so that after the last line is read, it starts over from the first line. `zip` takes a line from each file together.